# Controller firing twice if using $compile on directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a simple angular application thats use directives and dynamically append content to directive using link method. I have to compile that new contents, but if i do so it seems that controller called twice.

```
app.directive('comment', function ($compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div class="commentItem" ng-controller="MainCtrl">' +
                  '<span class="comment">{{comment.message}}</span>' +
                  '<span class="replyToComment" ng-click="doSmth()">doSmth</span>' + 
              '</div>',
    scope: {
        comment: '='
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        if (angular.isArray(scope.comment.comments)) {
            element.append("<comments comments='comment.comments'></comments>");
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        }
    }
};});
```

Is there a way to avoid this?

I tried to do like described in [this](http://www.ngroutes.com/questions/AUy0WRZ3JGEimGEpErxr/why-does-the-mouse-click-in-parent-fires-twice-when-a-directive-is-injected-duri.html) post, but that is not work for me.
Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZGkou3uie0vu3JKzPyMn).

Comment: why do you need ``ng-controller="MainCtrl"`` inside the template?

Comment: @BettySt I have some methods to work with comment (like, reply etc.)

Comment: maybe you can move these functions in your directive link function!

Comment: @BettySt even if i move these methods in a link function ng-click still call them twice. http://plnkr.co/edit/1629eB8iMzIaslmSXwe2

Comment: Workaround (I'll fix and make as an asnwer): http://plnkr.co/edit/GnQ6HtjbIw0n9wKxUiBP?p=preview

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I edited your [previous code](http://plnkr.co/edit/1629eB8iMzIaslmSXwe2), sincerely think there is an even better way.

What was happening is that previously you were adding multiple event listeners at the same html element.

Now, i'm destroying everything before compiling again.

```
app.directive('comment', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div class="commentItem">' +
                      '<span class="comment">{{comment.message}}</span>' +
                      '<span class="replyToComment" ng-click="doSmth()">doSmth</span>' + 
                  '</div>',
        scope: {
            comment: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            if (angular.isArray(scope.comment.comments)) {
                element.append("<comments comments='comment.comments'></comments>");
                var html = element.html();
                // Removing all contents and old listeners
                element.contents().remove();
                // Creating a new element
                element.html(html);
                // Adding new listeners
                $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            }
            scope.doSmth = function() {
               alert('!');
            }
        }
    };
});
```

```js
var app = angular.module('example', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.comments = [{
    message: 'parent 1',
    comments: [{
      message: 'p1_child1'
    }, {
      message: 'p1_child2',
      comments: [{
        message: 'p1c2_child1'
      }]
    }]
  },{
    message: 'parent 2'
  },{
    message: 'parent 3'
  }];
});
app.directive('comments', function() {
     return {
         restrict: 'E',
         replace: true,
         template: '<div class="commentBlock">'+
                      '<comment ng-repeat="comment in comments" comment="comment"></comment>' +
                  '</div>',
         scope: {
             comments: '='
         }
     };
});
app.directive('comment', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div class="commentItem">' +
                      '<span class="comment">{{comment.message}}</span>' +
                      '<span class="replyToComment" ng-click="doSmth()">doSmth</span>' + 
                  '</div>',
        scope: {
            comment: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            if (angular.isArray(scope.comment.comments)) {
                element.append("<comments comments='comment.comments'></comments>");
                var html = element.html();
                element.contents().remove();
                element.html(html);
                $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            }
            scope.doSmth = function() {
               alert('!');
            }
        }
    };
});
```

```css
/* Put your css in here */
.commentItem {
  border: 1px dashed black;
  margin: 20px;
}
.replyToComment {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  color: mediumblue;
}
.comment {
  font-size: larger;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
.commentBlock:not(:first-of-type) {
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.replyToComment:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="example">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <comments comments="comments"></comments>
  </body>
</html>
```